# flask_executor future.result() throws TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading, future

I'm trying to get result from the process that I created to run in the background using flask_executor. This are methods in use:

```
    def scan_and_collect( self ):
    self.data_collector.collect()
    self.clearing_requester.request()
    return "Whatever!"

def scan_and_collect_async( self ):
    task_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
    self.executor.submit_stored(task_id, self.scan_and_collect())
    return jsonify({'task_id': task_id})

def task_status(self, task_id):
    if not self.executor.futures.done(task_id):
        future_status = self.executor.futures._state(task_id)
        return jsonify({'status': future_status})
    future = self.executor.futures.pop(task_id)
    return jsonify({'status': 'done', 'result': future.result()})
```

My problem is that whenever I call task_status method i got *TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*.
I found that future_result returns *<bound method Future.result of <Future at 0x219fed6f510 state=finished raised TypeError>>*.
Thanks in advance for any hints on the error.

Comment: You submit a string to your executor, not a callable: `self.executor.submit_stored(task_id, self.scan_and_collect())`. Remove last parens.

Comment: And that's the answer! Please create an answer with the same content. I don't want to take over your credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `scan_and_collect_async` you submit a **return value** of `scan_and_collect` to executor. In your case the return value is a string.

Executor [expects a callable](https://flask-executor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#basic-usage) to run, optionally followed by args and kwargs to pass to that callable.

So, the correct implementation would be

```py
def scan_and_collect_async(self):
    task_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
    self.executor.submit_stored(task_id, self.scan_and_collect)
    return jsonify({'task_id': task_id})
```